# How do I convert a vector like $\vec{A}=6 \hat{i} + \hat{j}$ to spherical coordinates?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

Given a vector,
$$\vec{A}=6 \hat{i} + \hat{j}$$
My question is how do I convert it into spherical form and is my conversion correct?

My approach:

I calculated $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ and it came out to be $\sqrt{37}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\arctan(\frac{1}{6})$,
According to me the converted vector is, 
$$\vec{A}=\sqrt{37} \hat{r} + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\hat{\phi} + \frac{\pi}{2}\hat{\theta}$$

Do I have to convert i, j, k to spherical form?

Comment: A note of caution: "I calculated $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\phi}$ and it came out to be $\sqrt{37}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\arctan(\frac{1}{6})$" $-$ the first three objects are vectors, and the final three objects are scalars. You probably want to examine in detail the chain of thought that led you to put an equals sign between the two.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, the unit vectors *themselves* depend on the position $(\theta, \phi)$. So, the result depends on which point the vector is associated with. For example, consider the unit vector $\mathbf{\hat i}$. If it is located at $(1,0,0)$ in Cartesian coordinates, it would be represented as $\mathbf{\hat r}$ in spherical coordinates. If it were instead located at $(0,-1,0)$, it would be represented as $\mathbf{\hat ϕ}$ instead. So the answer depends on where the vector is.

Identify the point associated with the vector. Find the coordinates of this point in $(r, \theta, \phi)$ first, and then convert the unit vectors. The standard conversions apply. 
\begin{align}
r & = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\\
\theta & = \arccos{\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}}\\
\phi & = \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{\hat r} & = \sin\theta \cos\phi \, \mathbf{\hat x} + \sin\theta \sin\phi \, \mathbf{\hat y} + \cos\theta \, \mathbf{\hat z}
\\
\mathbf{\hat θ} & = \cos\theta \cos\phi \, \mathbf{\hat x} + \cos\theta \sin\phi \, \mathbf{\hat y} - \sin\theta \, \mathbf{\hat z}
\\
\mathbf{\hat ϕ} & = -\sin\phi \, \mathbf{\hat x} + \cos\phi \, \mathbf{\hat y}
\end{align}

Note: The correct quadrant needs to be accounted for when finding $\phi$. See [$\mathrm {atan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: Can you tell me what is the converted form?

Comment: @Sahil Silare: Which point is your vector located at?

Comment: I was given a vector $\vec{A} = y\hat{i} + (x+z)\hat{j}$ at the point $(-2,6,3)$

Comment: @Sahil Silare: Unfortunately, this is not a homework help site, so I am not supposed to provide the solution. Find the coordinates in terms of $(r, \theta, \phi)$ first, and then convert the components.

Comment: But it's not a homework and further, I've shown my approach.

Comment: @SahilSilare The site's [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) holds regardless of the origin of the question. Requests for explicit calculations like this one are off-topic here; user7777777 has correctly explained the formalism, but the specific computation is a job for you.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the help!